# SAP CAP switch off annotations of specific service

Tags: javascript, odata, sap-cap

i woul'd like to use a sap cap service in an c# application (odata feed service/odata client). This odata client doesn't work with annoations in the $metadata file.
How can i switch off all annotations for a specific service? Via server.js? Via service implemantion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create another service with projection (and without any annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Use `cds.persistence.exclude` annotation in the service which you want to switch off the annotation for.